# search for existing multiple KB files on multiple servers

Tags: powershell, hotfix

I have a script that will read server names in from a text file and then search for a specific KB update filename which works fine.

But what if I want to have each server searched in the `serverlist.txt` file searched for multiple KB update files? How could I do that?

```
$CheckComputers = get-content c:\temp\Path\serverlist.txt
# Define Hotfix to check
$CheckHotFixKB = "KB1234567";
foreach($CheckComputer in $CheckComputers)
{
 $HotFixQuery = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $CheckComputer | Where-Object {$_.HotFixId -eq $CheckHotFixKB} | Select-Object -First 1;
 if($HotFixQuery -eq $null)
 {
  Write-Host "Hotfix $CheckHotFixKB is not installed on $CheckComputer";
 }
 else
 {
  Write-Host "Hotfix $CheckHotFixKB was installed on $CheckComputer on by " $($HotFixQuery.InstalledBy);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set your KB's in an array:

```
$CheckHotFixKB = @(
"KB1234567"
"KB5555555"
"KB6666666"
"KB7777777"
)
```

And then do a nested foreach:

```
foreach($CheckComputer in $CheckComputers)
{
 foreach ($hotfix in $CheckHotFixKB) {
 $HotFixQuery = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $CheckComputer | Where-Object {$_.HotFixId -eq $hotfix} | Select-Object -First 1;
 if($HotFixQuery -eq $null)
 {
  Write-Host "Hotfix $hotfix is not installed on $CheckComputer";
 }
 else
 {
  Write-Host "Hotfix $hotfix was installed on $CheckComputer on by " $($HotFixQuery.InstalledBy);
 } }
}
```

Comment: no problem, please click the checkbox for "answered", if you don't mind :)

Comment: One thing is the output will list all the KB files in each line against each server so if one KB file is missing it does not identify which one.

Comment: Forgot to update the variables in the if/else statements, should be good now.

Comment: Very good, looking clean now, and should be set to "answered" now,  thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one query is better for check multi hotfixes

```
$NeededHotFixes = @('KB2670838','KB2726535','KB2729094','KB2786081','KB2834140')
Write-Host "Verify prerequisites hotfixes for IE11."
$InstalledHotFixes = (Get-HotFix).HotFixId
$NeededHotFixes | foreach {
  if ($InstalledHotFixes -contains $_) {
     Write-Host -fore Green "Hotfix $_ installed";
   } else {
     Write-Host -fore Red "Hotfix $_ missing";
  }
}
```

enjoy ;-)